# How can I check if an insert executed?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

How can I check if an insert executed?

```php
$s = Visitor::insert($items);
```

Variable `$s`contains the inserted object, not a boolean type.

Comment: Unless you've got this in a `try`/`catch` block that's ignoring errors, a failed `insert` should cause an immediate exception, which tends to be a pretty clear sign.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$s->exists` will tell you if the entry is in the database or not.

Comment: It should also throw an exception if `insert()` fails for some reason.

Comment: No it does not make an additional query.

Comment: @OPV `exists` does not cause additional queries.

Comment: How to use like `if ($s->exists){}`

Answer (score 3):

Another good check is to use

```
$s = Visitor::insertGetId($items);

if($s)
{
  // inserted
}
```

Answer (score 0):

another method is to use `wasRecentlyCreated`:

```
$s = Visitor::insert($items);

if ($s->wasRecentlyCreated === true) { //check if a new row was created 
    return 'true';
}
```